How does Room know how match a TypeConverter function to the appropriate datatype?
I created a dummy Entity class:
@Entity
data class Entity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    val data1: DataClass1? = null,
    val data2: DataClass2? = null
)

data class DataClass1(
    val text: String = "",
    val c: Char = ' '
)

data class DataClass2(
    val num1: Float = 0.0f,
    val num2: Long = 0,
)

Then I created a Converter class:
@ProvidedTypeConverter
class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun A_YYYYY(json: String): DataClass2 = Gson().fromJson(json, DataClass2::class.java)
    @TypeConverter
    fun Z_YYYYY(data: DataClass2): String = Gson().toJson(data)
    @TypeConverter
    fun A_XXXXX(json: String): DataClass1 = Gson().fromJson(json, DataClass1::class.java)
    @TypeConverter
    fun Z_XXXXX(data: DataClass1): String = Gson().toJson(data)
}

where I purposely gave the methods nonsense names and changed the order - the converter's method for the DataClass2 is first and for the DataClass1 is second (the opposite to the order in the Entity class).
So how does Room know how to match the methods in the generated file?
The code in an auto generated file Dao_Impl:
  @Override
  public Object getEntityById(final long id, final Continuation<? super Entity> arg1) {
    final String _sql = "SELECT * FROM entity WHERE id = ?";
    final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 1);
    int _argIndex = 1;
    _statement.bindLong(_argIndex, id);
    final CancellationSignal _cancellationSignal = DBUtil.createCancellationSignal();
    return CoroutinesRoom.execute(__db, false, _cancellationSignal, new Callable<Entity>() {
      @Override
      @Nullable
      public Entity call() throws Exception {
        final Cursor _cursor = DBUtil.query(__db, _statement, false, null);
        try {
          final int _cursorIndexOfId = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "id");
          final int _cursorIndexOfData1 = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "data1");
          final int _cursorIndexOfData2 = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "data2");
          final Entity _result;
          if (_cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final Long _tmpId;
            if (_cursor.isNull(_cursorIndexOfId)) {
              _tmpId = null;
            } else {
              _tmpId = _cursor.getLong(_cursorIndexOfId);
            }
            final DataClass1 _tmpData1;
            final String _tmp;
            if (_cursor.isNull(_cursorIndexOfData1)) {
              _tmp = null;
            } else {
              _tmp = _cursor.getString(_cursorIndexOfData1);
            }
            _tmpData1 = __converters().A_XXXXX(_tmp);
            final DataClass2 _tmpData2;
            final String _tmp_1;
            if (_cursor.isNull(_cursorIndexOfData2)) {
              _tmp_1 = null;
            } else {
              _tmp_1 = _cursor.getString(_cursorIndexOfData2);
            }
            _tmpData2 = __converters().A_YYYYY(_tmp_1);
            _result = new Entity(_tmpId,_tmpData1,_tmpData2);
          } else {
            _result = null;
          }
          return _result;
        } finally {
          _cursor.close();
          _statement.release();
        }
      }
    }, arg1);
  }

 private synchronized Converters __converters() {
    if (__converters == null) {
      __converters = __db.getTypeConverter(Converters.class);
    }
    return __converters;
  }

The specific parts where the converter functions are matched to the data:
 final int _cursorIndexOfData1 = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "data1");
 final int _cursorIndexOfData2 = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "data2");


//.............................
 if (_cursor.isNull(_cursorIndexOfData1)) {
              _tmp = null;
            } else {
              _tmp = _cursor.getString(_cursorIndexOfData1);
            }
            _tmpData1 = __converters().A_XXXXX(_tmp);

//.............................

if (_cursor.isNull(_cursorIndexOfData2)) {
              _tmp_1 = null;
            } else {
              _tmp_1 = _cursor.getString(_cursorIndexOfData2);
            }
            _tmpData2 = __converters().A_YYYYY(_tmp_1);

There isn't any:
__converters().forEach{ it ->
    if(_tmp_1.dataType == it.dataType){
          //some code
        }
}


or something like that. So how does it know that?

Based on the function signature. Each converter method should receive 1 parameter and have non-void return type - https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/TypeConverter

You say:-
There isn't any:

__converters().forEach{ it ->
    if(_tmp_1.dataType == it.dataType){
          //some code
        }
}

This is because the decision, as to what type converter applies is undertaken at compile time and thus you have:-
_tmpData1 = __converters().A_XXXXX(_tmp);

and then later:-
_tmpData2 = __converters().A_YYYYY(_tmp_1);

As for how the decision is made, it is according to the types in the function's signature (parameter type when inserting and return type when retrieving) matching the class's type being inserted/extracted.
So val data1: DataClass1? = null, is a type of DataClass1 and hence function A_XXXXX is used as it returns a type of DataClass1 when data is extracted. When data is inserted, likewise by signature/type it would utilise the Z_XXXXX function.

The input data-type is being defined in the annotated data-model class.
The TypeConverter just converts it into a data-type, which can be stored.
While I have the impression, that you may abuse TypeConverter
and should rather use the @Embedded annotation in such scenario.
You may be able to read/write JSON, but you can't properly query it.
